# How to create an interface with limited set of index in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that takes in variable of type `Record<string, string>`, how do I create a type of a limited set of index without ts compiler error.

Is it possible to create an interface with limited set of index of certain type?

```
type MyRecord = Record<string, string>

interface MyA {
    index1: string
    index2: 'true' | 'false'
}

function fn(a: MyRecord) {
    //do something
}

const myA: MyA = {
    index1: 'index',
    index2: 'true'
}
fn(myA) // error: Index signature is missing in type 'MyA'.
```

Unless I change MyA to be `type My = {...}`

Comment: If the function accepts `MyA` why type it `MyRecord`?

Comment: It sounds like you want `function fn<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(a: T) {}` instead of `function fn(a: MyRecord) {}`, unless you really expect that every possible key will have a `string` property, in which case `fn()` shouldn't accept a `MyA` at all.  Maybe you need to explain your use case better or show more examples?

Comment: `fn` is from other lib that I have no control. Yes I want `MyA`'s keys to be all strings but also a limit set of strings

Comment: Not sure if it's the best solution but
`type MyA = {...}`
seems to be a workaround. Although it makes the TS happy but it's not a answer to my original question

Answer (score 0):

You can always add an index signature to your type:

```
interface MyA {
  index1: string
  index2: 'true' | 'false'
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

The index signature must be compatible with your other properties (in this case `string` is compatible).

Comment: However in that case `const a: MyA = {
    index1: 'as',
    index2: 'true',
    something: 'asd'
}` is also valid. I don't want extra index for object of type MyA